# If a degree $n$ polynomial has $f(k)=k/(k+1)$ for $k=0,1,\ldots,n$, what is $f(n+1)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, lagrange-interpolation

> Suppose $f(x)\in K[x]$, $\deg f(x)=n$ and $f(k)=k/(k+1)$ for any $k=0,1,2,\ldots ,n$, what is $f(n+1)$?

I have a vague memory that there is a very clever trick that can solve this problem easily, but I simply can't recall how.

I have tried using brutal force, applying Lagrange interpolation formula. But the result looks very ugly (a sum that I don't know how to reduce). Certainly that's not the desirable approach here.

Comment: What's $K$? Any field?

Comment: "brutal force" lol

Comment: @DanielR yes a number field. The book doesn't specify it

Comment: @GregoryGrant. Sort of. ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

Let $g(x)=(x+1)f(x)-x$. This is a polynomial with degree $n+1$ and you know its roots, namely $x=0,1,2, \ldots ,n$. Thus
$$g(x)=Ax(x-1)(x-2) \dotsb (x-n),$$
where $A$ can be determined to be $A=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Can $A$ be determined?

Comment: @ajotatxe Yes $A$ can be determined because so far $f(x)=\frac{x[A(x-1)(x-2)\dotsb (x-n)+1]}{x+1}$. For $f$ to be a polynomial of degree $n$, the numerator should have $x=-1$ as a root. That will give you the $A$.

Comment: @ajotatxe. Yes. Later you'll have to use A for calculation